# php exec in the background with WAMP on Windows

Tags: php

with the following code i can call a php script and pass some variables into it

```
$cmd = 'php -f C:/wamp/www/np/myphpscript.php '.$var1;


exec($cmd);
```

this way my called script works,  but , i need that process to be in the background , i dont want to wait for the script to finish, is there any way of doing that using wamp on windows ? 
been doing some reading and some add a `&` at the end of the command, or a `> NUL` , now i noticed some of them are for linux , is there such a command for wamp on windows ? if there is please share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Due to the way the `exec()` command waits for the program to finish executing, it's very difficult to do this with vanilla `exec()`. I came across [these solutions](http://www.somacon.com/p395.php), and this one should work:

```
$rshell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$rexec = $rshell->Run("php -f C:/wamp/www/np/myphpscript.php ".$var1, 0, false);
```

The `WScript.Shell->Run` command takes 3 arguments: the command (you can optionally add output redirection), window mode (0 = hidden), and wait it should wait to finish. Because the 3rd argument is false, this PHP should return immediately.

**Original Solution**: As [this post](https://superuser.com/a/591084) suggests, you should try `START /B cmd`. It is virtually the Linux equivalent of `cmd &` in that it runs the command asynchronously, in the background, without user interaction or opening a new shell.

Because this will return immediately, PHP won't wait for it to finish, and the `exec()` command will not receive any output. Instead, try using shell output redirection. Your PHP given code would look like this:

```
$cmd = 'start /b "" php -f C:/wamp/www/np/myphpscript.php '.$var1.' >C:/wamp/www/np/output.txt';
exec($cmd);
```

Comment: could you please provide an example on how to call that inside php code ? using popen or something ?

Comment: le mme see, im falling asleep here a sec

Comment: runs the script, but not on the background, same as i have right now...hangs for while it finishes

Comment: k , the same result, hangs while executing, what im doing in that script is sending some data into google drive, usually takes around 10 seconds

Comment: Okay I added a major edit to the solution, please tell me if the `WScript.Shell` works for you.

Comment: finally had time to log in today man ill check now to see, btw i came across that one, and it did opened up a mspain.exe or a notepad.exe depending on the ones they had, on the background, but i think i had it wrong cause it will not run my php script, ill let u know in a jiffy

Comment: $rshell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$rexec = $rshell->Run("php -f C:/wamp/www/np/myphpscript.php ".$var1, 0, false);   that did the trick, seems i had it messedup at the php -f part, running like a gloove, ty so much, owe you a six pack

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are running and if you get a response to your command. But maybe it helps if you open a tab for each command. So you can see responses of each running script and at the end you can call javascript to close the tab.

Comment: the script runs and  i get my responses ok but i need it to be on the background, ive seen the result and it does what i need, only it wont run in the background. which is the only point in doing it

Comment: do your start the script over a browser or directly dos shell?

Comment: the script is called on the click of a submit button, it performs ok , but not as i wish, in the background , where you dont have to wait X seconds for it to finish

Answer (score 0):

> **You must set the variable php on windows environment !**

**If you have already done so skip the tutorials steps:**

```
 1. Open:
        My Computer => Properties => Change Settings

 2. Select the tab: Advanced

 3. Click Environment Variables: Variable system

 4. Click the button New
        Add the name of the environment variable. Example = php
        Add the path to executable php.exe. Example = D:\xampp\php\php.exe
```

**Create a file myscript.php**

> The variariaveis **$argc** and **$argv** are native php.
>
> You will notice that $ argc always carries the same value as the
>   result of calling count (**$argv**) in any case **$argc** is the standard
>   used and is a few milliseconds faster by being in memory (if that
>   makes any difference in performance your script).

```
//\n skip line
echo "\n\n";
//echo test debug
echo "Print Total Args : ";
//Print return variavel $argc
print_r($argc);
//\n skip line
echo "\n\n";
//echo test debug
echo "Print Array Args : \n\n";
//Print return variavel $argv
print_r($argv);
echo "\n";
// You can retrieve the arguments in the normal way.
$myvar_count = $argc;
$myvar_array_args = $argv;
```

**Or if you want to set is not the environment variable, simply can call the path**

```
Example: D:\xampp\php\php.exe myscript.php argument1 2 3 4 5
```

**Retorn the Prompt in Windows**

```
Total Args : 5

Array Args :

Array
(
    [0] => test.php
    [1] => argumento1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

> **I hope this helps! See you later!**